# Add a new row to the top of a jQuery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to add a new row into a datatable which should be placed in the top of the table and I've used sorting plugin, but it failed.

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: You can have a template of `row` stored in a variable. You can get the first row of the table `$('table').find('tr:first')` and `.prepend(rowTemplate)`

Comment: Sorry, Since it has pagination it won't work, it will be added to the top of the last page .

Comment: Could you make a fiddle of what you are doing?

Comment: yes... Done a sample.. check this http://jsfiddle.net/cvLRg/41/

Comment: since the rows will reorder upon sorting, adding a row to top can be difficult. You can do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/cvLRg/56/ (hide the first column). But this will not work if you sort some column and they append or prepend

Answer (score 5):

After quite some time I could solve this problem in my table with the built in **[order](http://datatables.net/reference/api/order())()** function. (No additional plugin needed)

```
    var table = $('#adapterTable').DataTable();

    $('#newButton').on( 'click', function () {
        var row = ["<button id='savebutton'>save</button>","<input name='titel'/>"];
        table.row.add(row).draw( false );

        table.order([1, 'asc']).draw();
        table.order([0, 'asc']).draw();
    } );
```

This works because my table has ID's in the first column and text field in the second column.

My inserted row contains a save button in the ID column and an input field in the second column.

If I now sort the second Column ascending the input box will be shown on top.
To restore the ordering by ID I just make one more order() on the ID column. This somehow doesn't affect the row with the button, just the rows with numeric values.

```
table.order([0, 'asc']).draw();
```

This also is more of a workaround and it depends on the content of your table. With plain Text you might have to combine it with a **hidden column** just for ordering, or another trick. But you can use datatable functions and don't need to manipulate the table directly.

Comment: Hi, I've tried your solutions, but I don't know why the input text is not available to be filled in. Do you know why,.?

Comment: im not sure if I understand your question right.
you can write a text into the input box with a value attribute: <input value='yourtext'>

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the sort order of the table is whatever order the server returns the data array in. The client does not do any additional sorting (`'ordering'` is set to `false`). In order to add a new row to the beginning of the data array client-side, I did the following:

- get the raw `table.data()` data array
- insert my new row at the beginning of the array
- clear the table and re-add all the rows

```
let newdata = Array.from(table.data());
newdata.unshift(['my', 'new', 'row']);
table.clear();
for (const row of newdata) {
  table.row.add(row);
}
table.draw();
```

Comment: Great solution and even pretty performant compared to others I tried. Also if you have an ordered table and only want to display the new entries temporarily on top, you can just use "table.draw(false)" which won't trigger the ordering.

Answer (score 1):

This workaround might help:

- Add the row to the datatable object via the api (so you'll have the data available when you sort or paginate)
- Don't redraw (so the new row isn't drawn at the bottom)
- Add the same row to the top of the table via `.prepend()`

```
var employersTable = $('#employersTable').DataTable();
$('#addRow').click(function(){
    var row = $('<tr>')
        .append('<td>added row</td>')
        .append('<td>Test 2</td>')
        .append('<td>123</td>')
        .append('<td>2014-05-09</td>')
        .append('<td>No</td>')
        .append('<td>blub</td>')

    employersTable.row.add(row);
    $('#employersTable tbody').prepend(row);
});
```

Important (maybe) drawback: it won't automatically paginate when you add rows.

Working example at your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvLRg/101/).

Comment: It's a bad solution to manipulate table directly as this breaks ordering and pagination.

Comment: I know, that's why I called it a "workaround". Since what the OP asked by definition is _breaking ordering_, I thought it could be good enough. Also, since I add the row to the data, on your next interaction with the datatable, the sorting and pagination will work again.

Comment: If you use this method, basic datatable functionalities will not work!

Answer (score 0):

The add method will push the row to aiDisplayMaster array in jquery.dataTables.js. So you can change the location the rows in aiDisplayMaster. the following is the code.

```
table = $("table").dataTable() //not DataTable() function
dt = table.api()
obj = {"id":131,"name":" 111  test"}
dt.row.add(obj);
var aiDisplayMaster = table.fnSettings()["aiDisplayMaster"];
irow = aiDisplayMaster.pop();
aiDisplayMaster.unshift(irow);
dt.draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#addRowBtn').on('click', function() {
    var t = $('#example').DataTable();
    var newRow = t.row.add([]).order( [ 1, 'asc' ] ).draw(false).node();
    $(newRow).prependTo('#example tbody');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#addRow').on('click', function () {
  var newRow = $('<tr>').append(
    $('<td>').html('<input type="text" placeholder="Employee Number" id="emp_number" name="emp_number">'),
    $('<td>').html('<input type="text" placeholder="dd" id="name" name="name">'),
    $('<td>').html('<select size="1" id="post" name="post"><option value="" selected="selected">Choose Post</option> <% for(var i=0; i<posts.length; i++) {%><option value="<%= posts[i].PostID %>"><%= posts[i].PostName %></option><% } %></select>'),
    $('<td>').html('<input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" id="start_time" name="start_time">'),
    $('<td>').html('<input type="text" placeholder="End Time" id="end_time" name="end_time">'),
    $('<td>').html('<input type="text" placeholder="Hours" id="hours" name="hours" readonly>'),
    $('<td>').html('<button>Save</button>')
  );

  var table = $('#example');
  table.find('tbody').prepend(newRow);
});
```